Vibrato in Liszt’s Oeuvre
Liszt sometimes writes the expressive term Vibrato. Vibrato. What does it mean on the piano. We can wiggle our fingers all we want but once the key is pressed the hammer is propelled and strikes the string and then bounces off. There is no possibility of attaining a true vibrato. I would like some guidance on this subject. I will explain my educated opinion on this matter but I would like advice from professional musicians.
My theory: Vibrato in Liszt means to put the right pedal down and let the chord vibrate without holding down on any of the keys. It is more along the lines of Debussy's laissez vibrer “let vibrate/ring.”
Was Liszt intending a true vibrato, a quasi vibrato or a harmonious vibration/ringing facilitated by how the note(s) are played with the right pedal?

It doesn't necessarily mean the same thing each time it's used. That is, the meaning may depend on context. I suggest referencing a specific piece, and an image is highly encouraged.

I posted some of the passages I had in question. These are a few of the spots but they are almost everywhere in his text

That's helpful, but what piece is it from?

I was under the impression that vibrato in this context meant a rapid vibration of the note, as if you are vibrating one finger to hit the note repeatedly. ...Or at least give that impression in the example's case.

The more I research this, the more clear it becomes clear the importance of what piece this is. It's date of composition, in particular, may be particularly crucial, as well as where and when Liszt might have performed it. The core question is what piano(s) he was using at the time.

This is a widely discussed thing, and you should be able to get many theories by doing a simple web search. But you will most likely not find anything definite.
Now some people would assume that Liszt would have actually intended you to vibrate your fingers on the keys, believing this to actually cause an audible effect.
I’d interpret this differently: Liszt (very inspired by Schubert’s writing for piano) is known for his piano works, but he is actually an orchestral composer. And when Liszt writes for piano, he thinks very much in terms of an orchestral language. Actually Liszt really got popular in his time doing things like playing works for orchestra on a piano.
So in this sense I think a reasonable interpretation of this is not an instruction to actually play vibrato on the piano, but to indicate that when writing the passage he had string vibrato in mind. So in this sense the term would be read as an indication for a certain expressive timbre.
Another possible reading could be that vibrato does not strictly mean “wobble the pitch”. Even on instruments that do have vibrato there are two different types of vibrato, being a pitch vibrato and an intensity vibrato (the second is generally found with things that are breath dependent, especially in singing). But the term essentially means “vibrated”. And “to vibrate” has been historically used in different ways, and one of which is simply to have something vibrate, i.e. create a sound. This you can see in the french instruction « Laissez vibrer », indicating that the instrument should not be dampened, but left ringing.
In this sense such a vibrato could also be read as an instruction to play with a ringing quality.

It doesn't affect the main point, but in contemporary terms, isn't a variation in volume known as tremolo rather than vibrato?

Aaron: Liszt Années de Pelerinage 1st Year Suisse. Chapel of William Tell

@gidds Tremolo is commonly understood to be a (fast) repetition of a single note or between two notes. A vibrato in intensity is not a repeated note, but a single note with a vibration of intensity, usually a lot slower than what you have with tremolo.
